# JPA 2 Constructor Expression cannot use constructor

Tags: java, constructor, jpa-2.0

I use OpenJPA 2.1.1 on WebSphere Application Server 8.

I want to create object from SELECT query using constructor expression:

```
String queryString = "SELECT NEW mypackage.StatisticDataObject(c.source, "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN (c.validTo <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND c.expireNoProblem LIKE 'N') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN (c.validTo <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND c.expireNoProblem LIKE 'Y') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN (c.validTo > :timestamp30 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN (c.validTo > :timestamp10 AND c.validTo <= :timestamp30 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), "
    + "SUM(CASE WHEN (c.validTo > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND c.validTo <= :timestamp10 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) )"
    + "FROM MYTABLE c GROUP BY c.source";
TypedQuery<StatisticDataObject> q = em.createQuery(queryString,
                StatisticDataObject.class);
q.setParameter("timestamp30", getTimestampIn(30));
q.setParameter("timestamp10", getTimestampIn(10));
```

Constructor:

```
public StatisticDataObject(String name, Integer expired,
        Integer expiredButOK, Integer expireIn10Days, Integer expireIn30Days,
        Integer expireGT30Days) {
    this.name = name;
    this.expired = expired;
    this.expiredButOK = expiredButOK;
    this.expireIn10Days = expireIn10Days;
    this.expireIn30Days = expireIn30Days;
    this.expireGT30Days = expireGT30Days;
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Query "SELECT NEW mypackage StatisticDataObject(c.source, ... at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:872)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:315)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:331)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Es wurde kein Konstruktor für "class mypackage.StatisticDataObject" mit den Argumenttypen "[class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]" gefunden, um die Daten einzutragen. 
// ENGLISH Translation: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no constructor "class mypackage.StatisticDataObject" with argument type "[class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]".
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.FillStrategy$NewInstance.findConstructor(FillStrategy.java:139)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.FillStrategy$NewInstance.fill(FillStrategy.java:144)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultShape.pack(ResultShape.java:362)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultShapePacker.pack(ResultShapePacker.java:48)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl$PackingResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(QueryImpl.java:2082)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.rop.EagerResultList.<init>(EagerResultList.java:36)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.toResult(QueryImpl.java:1251)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:1007)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:863)
    ... 84 more
```

If I run the query without NEW mypackage.StatisticDataObject() it works by using Object[]. Also the class of object[1-5] (.getClass()) is Integer.

So why does JPA return a String from SUM() instead of Integer when using the constructor expression?

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor take in count that the state of the field type in which you will apply **SUM** need to be numeric, and the result type must correspond on the field type. For example, if a Double field is summed , the result will be returned as Double,. If a Long field type is summed, the response will be returned as a Long.

It is the root cause of the problem, SUM not return a Integer type.

Comment: Thats right, it seems SUM returns a String. But why?